# Minecraft Forge block creation 1.16.5

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Im making a forge mod and am currently trying blocks. I cant fid any documentation on how to create a block and the tutorial I am watching isn't working. This is my code:

```
public class ModBlocks {
    public static final RegistryObject<Block> SILVER_ORE = register("silver_ore", () ->
            new Block(new AbstractBlock.Properties.create(Material.STONE).requiresCorrectToolForDrops().sound(SoundType.STONE)));

    static void register() {}

    private static <T extends Block> RegistryObject<T> registerNoItem(String name, Supplier<T> block) {
        return Registration.BLOCKS.register(name, block);
    }

    private static <T extends Block> RegistryObject<T> register(String name, Supplier<T> block) {
        RegistryObject<T>  ret = registerNoItem(name, block);
        Registration.ITEMS.register(name, () -> new BlockItem(ret.get(), new Item.Properties().tab(ItemGroup.TAB_BUILDING_BLOCKS)));
    }
}
```

The issue is with the

```
 new Block(new AbstractBlock.Properties.create(Material.STONE).requiresCorrectToolForDrops().sound(SoundType.STONE)));
```

line.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what isn't working? is it not compiling? is it crashing? is it not appearing in the creative tab?

Comment: @lenerdv my IDE says .create isnt a thing and it wont run. I was wondering if anyone could just tell me how you do it

Comment: try going to the forge discord?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.create` method isn't a thing anymore. You have to use the supplier like this :
`()-> new Block(AbstractBlock.Properties.of(Material.STONE).(*some preperties*)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you are calling `NEW AbstractBlock.Properties.create(/*...*/)`, and the compiler goes:

1. There's `new`, so I expect a constructor
2. There's `AbstractBlock.`*something* so there must be a nested type next
3. There's `Properties.`*something* so there must be a nested type next
4. There's `create(...)` so it must be the constructor, and `create` must be the nested type
5. There's no type named `AbstractBlock.Properties.create` so there must be an error

To solve this, just remove the `new` before `AbstractBlock`, you don't need it. It's sort of replaced by the `create` function, which is static and returns the new object itself.

Comment: Still got the issue! Error is:
error: cannot find symbol
            new Block(AbstractBlock.Properties.create(Material.STONE).requiresCorrectToolForDrops().sound(SoundType.STONE)));
                                              ^
  symbol:   method create(Material)
  location: class Properties

Comment: do you still have the `() -> ` in front?

Comment: Yes i do still have that

Answer (score 0):

It's the mappings.  AbstractBlock.Properties.create is in the MCP mappings and AbstractBlock.Properties.of is in the default "official" mappings.  See https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Tutorials/Creating_Forge_mods Step 3-1/2 on how to change mappings.

You can look at other blocks to see how they do it in the decompiled source that is added to your dev environment.  Checkout net.minecraft.block.Blocks.java

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class ModBlocks {
    public static final RegistryObject<Block> SILVER_ORE = register("silver_ore", () ->
        new Block(new AbstractBlock.Properties.of(Material.STONE).requiresCorrectToolForDrops().sound(SoundType.STONE)));

    static void register() {}

    private static <T extends Block> RegistryObject<T> registerNoItem(String name, Supplier<T> block) {
        return Registration.BLOCKS.register(name, block);
    }

    private static <T extends Block> RegistryObject<T> register(String name, Supplier<T> block) {
        RegistryObject<T>  ret = registerNoItem(name, block);
        Registration.ITEMS.register(name, () -> new BlockItem(ret.get(), new Item.Properties().tab(ItemGroup.TAB_BUILDING_BLOCKS)));
    }
}
```